# Need help regarding odometry using Encoder motor and raspberry pi

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, odometry

I am doing project on odometry using raspberry pi. I know that encoder motor will tell me how much distance my robot has covered, but I have no idea ho to implement completely. I just need guideline about which steps to follow. Till now I have interfaced motor with raspberry pi and counted the number of rotation. I have questions as follow?

How to plot map of odometry using which language and library?

If you know anything, just give me guideline about steps to follow.

Comment: Welcome! Please only ask one question. I edited your post and removed the second part about ros. You can ask about that in a separate question. Still, your question is somewhat unclear as you did not describe your robot at all, which makes it impossible to answer. Please [edit] your question and add that information. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a 2-motor differential drive robot, or one with some sort of car steering mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

You could maybe use Matlab to plot the position of your vehicle? This is how I'm trying to do that:
I have a 'logging'-program running on the Raspberry Pi that counts each sampling time the pulses from the encoders. This I log in a file. This file I upload in Matlab to calculate X and Y coordinate and the angle under which the vehicle is standing, assuming the vehicle starts at coordinate (0,0) and angle 0°.
These are the formula's I use. With 'triangle'-r and 'triangle'-l I mean the distance traveled by left and right wheel (can be calculated using pulses in log file and diameter of the wheel). Distance '2L' is the distance between the 2 wheels.

[image]

I wrote a [matlab GUI](http://nl.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gui.html) in which I can browse a data file (from the Pi), calculates the X and Y position every sampling period and plot this is an XY graph.

Ps: you didn't mention it, but I suppose you have a differential drive vehicle?!

Comment: Please note that you can insert mathematical formulas into your post with mathjax. This has the advantage that it can be edited more easily than an image. For example `$$\Theta_{k+1} = \Theta_{k} + \omega$$` gives $$\Theta_{k+1} = \Theta_{k} + \omega$$. You can also right click on any formula to see the code (Tex commands) that were used to create it. As this is close to Latex, it's a handy skill to have.